# How to check if the user has been added to LDAP group using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

I need to validate if the user has been added successfully to a particular group. The only option I can think of is using exception handling. Is there a better way of using LDAP response codes of any type.

```
public boolean addMemberToGroup(String groupName, Person p) {
        boolean status = false;
        Name groupDn = buildGroupDn(groupName);
        Name personDn = buildPersonDn(p);
        try {
            
            DirContextOperations ctx = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(groupDn);
            ctx.addAttributeValue(UNIQUE_MEMBER, personDn);
            ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(ctx);
            status  = true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            status =false;
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here is how i used to proceed:

- lookup the user i need to create on my active directory (returns false if it is true then the user already exists)
- Create the user
- look up the user again (returns true this time)